# Python - function setting external variable to user input as side effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I'm a casual gamer and hobbyist programmer who knows a bit of Python. I'm trying to make a simple text adventure game engine, so I need to get raw input from the player.

This is Python 3.2.2, so my line is this:

```
var = input("What do you want to do? ").lower()
```

And that line works, but rather than typing that whole line I'd like to make it into a function (something like "getinput()"). From what I've read about input() and functions I'm looking for a function that doesn't return anything, but changes another variable's state (here "var") as a "side effect."

I do have a working function "halt()" that takes no arguments:

```
def halt():
    input("(Press Enter to continue...) ")
    print("")
```

Calling "halt()" gives the prompt, waits for Enter, then prints a blank line and moves on, which I intended.

The function I'm trying to get to work looks like this:

```
def getinput(x):
    x = input("What do you want to do? ").lower()
    print("")
```

After defining getinput(x):

```
var = ""
getinput(var)
print(var)
```

That snippet does not print the user's input, and I'm confused as to why. What do I need to do to make this work in the intended fashion?

Is what I'm trying to do impossible with a function, or is there just something I don't know about scope? Should I be at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to make your `getinput()` function not return anything. Your code will be easier to understand if your function returns the input, since you'll be working *with* Python instead of *against* it.

Comment: This has been addressed many times, for one see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: If you want to get information from a function, then return information. That's what return values are for.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for helping out. Sorry I wasn't able to respond; posting this question was the last thing I did before I went to sleep.

@Mark Ransom I guess that wasn't one of the things that came up when I was looking for a previous answer. I pretty much searched for what terms are in the title of this question, but as it turns out I'm not supposed to be trying to work the code backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the issue is about scope. The x in this line:

```
x = input("What do you want to do? ").lower()
```

Does not change the value that is passed to it- it creates a new variable (also called x) in the local scope of the function.

The right way to do this would be:

```
def getinput():
    return input("What do you want to do? ").lower()

x = getinput()
print(x)
```

Comment: -1 It's not about scope, it's about the immutability of strings, and the fact that assignment in Python is a rebinding operation and not a mutating one.

Comment: It's still about scope. The line `x = 1` outside the function would have had a different effect. And you seem to be splitting hairs- did you read the rest of my answer?

Comment: Thanks, this was the most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: If you are going to use any version of Python before 3.x, definitely consider using the raw_input() function as the plain input() function only takes input that is SYNTACTICALLY VALID from the user, otherwise a SyntaxError will be raised.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but I've moved around what you've written above so that it will work. Here's what I suggest trying:

First the function getinput()...

```
def getinput():
    x = raw_input("What do you want to do? ").lower() #prompts for the value of x
    print "" #prints a blank line
    return x
```

Then the second part...

```
var = getinput()
print(var)
```

Comment: Your advice about `raw_input()` and `input()` is valid for Python 2.x, but in Python 3.x `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. That is, the OP was doing the right thing with `input()`.

Comment: Don't worry, I did the *exact* same thing while answering a question a few weeks ago. Pay it forwards. :3

Answer (score 1):

When you pass something to a Python function, it's generally impossible to modify it unless it's mutable. That restricts you to a small subset of Python types such as a list or dictionary.

```
def getinput(x):
    x[0] = input("What do you want to do? ").lower()
    print("")

var = [""]
getinput(var)
print(var[0])
```

You're far better off letting the function return a value. That's the way Python was meant to work.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a python string variable which is being passed by value to your `getinput` function, which means that your `getinput` function only modifies a local copy of the name "x", not the value pointed to by "x" from your calling scope.

Also in Python strings are immutable and so it is impossible to modify a string's underlying value in-place due to [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)/[hash consing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) - you merely create a new string. You should really be returning your value:

```
x = getinput()
```

But if you still want to stick to your existing design, you can pass this string variable by reference by wrapping it in a list or other reference type:

```
def getinput(li):
    li.append(input("What do you want to do? ").lower())
    print("")
```

usage:

```
x = []
getinput(x)
print x[0]
```